# Send dynamically created textfield data in array

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have dynamically created `UITextfield` using for loop and now i need to send the text contained in the `UITextfield` to an array inside button click and send back to another `viewcontroller`. But when I pass the data in array, then `textfield` data is sent blank. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: please put some code here...

Answer (score 1):

To do this you have to use delegate method.

For Ex:

Initialize the **Values** array before calling this method;

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++) 
{
  UITextField *text1 =[UITextField alloc]init];
  // set frame for text1
  text1.tag = i;
  text1.delegate=self;
}


-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
[Values setObject:textField.text atIndexedSubscript:textField.tag];
}
```

on passing array dont forget to add

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Please let me know if you have any help

Comment: Thanks Prakash, your code works. If text is not added in some textfield it should pass blank values. Is it possible?

Comment: initialize the array as NSArray *Values = [[NSArray alloc]initwithObjects (@"",@"",nil)]; initialize  with empty string (for number of textboxes). i-e if you have 5 initialize 5 empty string

Comment: But what if I don't know the count of textfields which would be added?

Comment: in for loop allocate values to the **Values** array using addobject.

Comment: Hi Prakash. Using in for loop works but if user doesnt go to last textfield, nothing is added in that array for last textfield. Can I add values for last text fields which are not accessed.

Comment: Hi Prakash. Could you help with above question. Thanks.